# How to force python to import only a specific version of OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, version, python-import

I need to install a specific version of OpenCV. How do I do this at the import stage?

I've seen some people use this method on other packages, and I tried to replicate for opencv, but it did not work... what's the correct statement for this method?...

```
import pkg_resources

pkg_resources.require("OpenCV==3.3.1")

import cv2
print('OpenCV version: ', cv2.__version__)
```

Comment: do you import openCV later on? Since you still need to import it

Comment: yes I do, I edited the question :D

Comment: did not worked...

Comment: Can you use virtual environments or anaconda? That would be the simplest and cleanest way.

Comment: I can't, my teacher wanted me to run it on console, so the evaluators would find my licence more programming-ish like :)))

Comment: virtual environments are completely fine with consoles

Answer (score -1):

You can just install a different version of OpenCV on https://opencv.org/releases/ and then put it into python...